# how to force (enable) window decorations on application

Tags: debian, fluxbox

I recently needed to join a "Zoom" meeting from my Debian workstation on which I use Fluxbox for my window manager.

The Zoom application starts in the upper left corner of my display with no titlebar or window decorations, so I cannot move it or otherwise manipulate it as I would with other windows.  (I can perform some actions by right-clicking on Zoom in the toolbar, but options there are limited).

The Zoom application doesn't provide any inline help nor did it come with a readme or man page, at least that I have been able to find.

Is there a way to instruct Fluxbox to force window decorations on this window, either before or after starting the tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a key to run `ToggleDecor`.  I have this in
~/.fluxbox/keys:

```
Mod1 t     :ToggleDecor
```

It's described in `man fluxbox-keys`

```
   ToggleDecor
       Toggles the presence of the window decorations (title bar, 
       window buttons, and resize bar).
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem and it turns out that the problem is that fluxbox doesn't have a compositor -- running a separate compositor (I use compton, but xcompmgr should work as well) solves this issue for me.