# Fluxbox and Zoom, How to get window decorations?

Tags: gentoo, fluxbox, window-decorations

I use fluxbox as my window manager. All of my other applications, besides the Zoom video conference application has window decorations, and they can be toggled on/off with the appropriate fluxbox key binding/command. Zoom does not. I has space above it for window decorations, and when I toggle them on/off this space disappears and comes back, but it never has the window decorations in it. How can I fix this?

In a related question, [how to force (enable) window decorations on application](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502964/how-to-force-enable-window-decorations-on-application), @Lars Kotthoff says this is a problem related to the fact that "fluxbox doesn't have a compositor." What is a compositor? How can one be used to solve this problem? (I don't need anything to be transparent, or have a drop shadow, which seems to be the primary function of a compositor, from what I've learned trying this so far.)

As requested, some versions:

```
$ fluxbox --version
Fluxbox 1.3.7-gentoo-r4 : (c) 2001-2015 Fluxbox Team 

$ uname -a
Linux kirk 4.19.44-gentoo #5 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 19 12:31:30 EDT 2020 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4800MQ CPU @ 2.70GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

$ eselect profile show
Current /etc/portage/make.profile symlink:
  default/linux/amd64/17.0/desktop
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/582762/edit) your post to include information on the Gentoo and fluxbox version you are using?

Comment: I also have the same issue with Gentoo. I run a setup where I have 2 monitors and to X11 server running, one for each monitor, so that I can change workspaces independently from each other. On `DISPLAY=:0.1` zoom and teamviewer have window decoration, on `DISPLAY=:0.1`, both have no window decoration. However, like user1958943 mentioned on the comments below, if you do a restart of fluxbox (I mean fluxbox `Restart` command), then both programs have a decoration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Slackware Linux and I had the same problem but I solved by
building Fluxbox manually from https://github.com/fluxbox/fluxbox and
replacing Fluxbox binary delivered by the OS with it.  Note that
`fluxbox --version` string stays the same as it's hardcoded in
fluxbox/version.h:

```
#define __fluxbox_version "1.3.7"
```

Of course I think it's a good practice to use system's package manager
to replace Fluxbox binary instead of just dropping a new binary in
`/usr/bin` or wherever Fluxbox lives on your system.

zoom-linux with decorations:

[image]

I can also toogle decorations using `ToggleDecor`. I guess the whole issue has something to do with client-side
decorations but I can't say for sure.

Comment: I had the same issue with zoom in fluxbox under arch linux, and installing fluxbox-git from AUR solved it. Thanks!

Comment: A workaround is to restart fluxbox after starting zoom. This will decorate the zoom window properly. The same problem also happened to me on zathura windows. This is on archlinux as well.

Comment: @user1958943 `ToggleDecor` did not work for me, but the restart did. Thanks